# AGPL Question Licensing

Tags: licensing

If Magento Community edition is released under AGPL does that mean I can demand that any user who has add-ons installed has to turn over the source code on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento uses OSL 3.0, not AGPL license. Also OSL doesn't cover add-ons, extensions and libraries that merely link to the software covered with OSL (otherwise it wouldn't be able to use Zend and Prototype frameworks, among other things).

Comment: okay thanks, sorry I thought I saw AGPL somewhere maybe it was an add-on.

Comment: I couldn't find in the text of the OSL that it does not cover add-ons, extensions and libraries. Also the example given about that it would otherwise not be possible to use Zend Framework is wrong, as Zend Framework is available under the lax BSD license that only requires preservation of copyright notice, list of conditions and disclaimer in the source-code (as Magento CE contains the source-code) and AFAIK these have been preserved. However the part that it's not AGPL is correct :)